# IBOutlet Visible after successful login, Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication

So i have a tableView that shows some information that i parse from the web. I also have a DetailViewController that shows additional information about the cell that the user clicks on.

Now I'm using a TabBarViewController and on the last tab bar i want to have a login section. If the user is logged in he/she will be able to change the information stored in the DetailViewController (there will be some UIButtons and some UILabels the user will be able to push and insert some text to.)

I tried to search on the web just as the title for this question has but I didn't find anything at all. So please if you could provide me maybe a name for this technique so i can look it up or even links for tutorials would be better. Any tips and suggestions would also be great!

BTW I'm thinking about using NSKeyChains (maybe other suggestions here?)

Comment: So you want to hide/show some elements in the screen depending if the user is logged or not, is it?

Comment: Correct! @GustavoBarbosa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

You have to link each element you want to show/hide in your `UIViewController` with an IBOutlet:

```
@interface YourViewController ()
   @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *yourLabel;
   @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *yourButton;
@end
```

And you can have a method to display/hide those elements depending if the user is logged or not, like this:

```
- (void)showOrHideButtonsDependingOnLoggedState()
{
    BOOL logged = // some method to discover if he/she is logged
    if (logged) {
        _yourLabel.hidden = NO; // depending if you to show or hide
        _yourLabel.hidden = YES;
    } else { 
        _yourLabel.hidden = NO;
        _yourLabel.hidden = YES;
    } 
}
```

and call it before your view appear or when the logged state changes.

If you have some confidential information about the user and want to have a secure place to store that, you are right about storing it inside the Keychain. There are a few libraries you can use to avoid the pain of store/loading it by your own. One of them is that: https://github.com/danielalves/NitroKeychain

Comment: Yea that will be good :). But the method to hide and make visible would be in the TableViewController right?

I haven o confidential information about the user. All i want to be able to do is to make some predefined users that will be able to login with a simple login/pass, is not keychain my choice then? @Gustavo Barbosa

Comment: Right. You can call it in you `viewDidLoad` or in your `viewWillAppear`, depending on your needs. If your login/pass is predefined, you have only to check if the inputs match them.

Comment: Great thanks. Regarding KeyChain, As i said i would not have any confidential information. All i want to do is to be able to store predefined user/passwords that i will give out to certain users so they can log in. Is keychain the choice for me or should i consider something else? @Gustavo Barbosa

Comment: Even if you choose Keychain, you have to store it in some way. And when you are storing it, you're passing its raw value. So maybe it will not be that best solution for your case. So perhaps you should store it in some `static NSString *const` or plist variables and compare it.

Comment: Would that work? Im thinking of putting the app on App Store then i think the best solution is to use a database to store the usernames and passwords? Or am i wrong? @Gustavo Barbosa

Comment: It is up to you. It will work. But if you prefer to store it using CoreData or a simple sqlite file, that's fine too. Just remember that if you pick the CoreData option, you have to save the date just once time per installation.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. But ur telling me to store all the usernames/password that i will give to the users that will have login access in a static NSString *const variable? and then compare it with the input for username/password if it finds a match? @Gustavo Barbosa

Comment: I just saw your comment about having several possible combinations of login/pass that could be valid. So, in this case, that option of using consts is not the best one, once you would have several if statements. In this case, I think the best approach is to have a sqlite file in your app and try to match the login/pass with one of them.

Comment: Great, one last question sorry for bothering you :P its my first app. Lets say we use an sqlite file in my app. If i needed to add/delete some users. Would that correspond to an update that the users will have to download from App Store? Cause I think i will have to add/remove users from time to time? @Gustavo Barbosa

Comment: Yes. If you have to change (add/delete) some user from that list, you have to upload a new app to the AppStore. If you don't want to do that, you have to store it in some place accessible via web. In this case, you can use something like parse.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 containers in your storyboard. One would be the login view controller, the other one would be your DetailViewController. 
Then you just have to hide the login view controller is the user is already logged in.
[This tutorial](http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers) might help you

Or you can also just present the login view controller modally so that the user is forced to login to acces the DetailViewController.
See [Apple's reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1)

Comment: I don't want to force because not all user will have the privilege to change stuff. Okay that sounds good. I also thought about this. What if i have a method in DetailViewController that makes the IBOutles visible. And then when the user is logged in I will just call the method and when the user is logged out then ill call another method to make them invisible again? @Imotep

Comment: That will work too. But the point you should focus in is : how much things should be updated in my controller's view depending on the user's login? If it's just hidding 1 or 2 parameters it's fine. But if things are more complicated, you should consider having 2 different controllers. That's way easier.

Comment: It would be two buttons, and 2 labels @Imotep i will consider your answer thank you :)